# Awk changes tabs to spaces

Tags: bash, awk

Data:

`Sandnes<space>gecom<tab>Hansen<tab>Ola<space>Timoteivn<space>10`

I am substituting a specific column (ex:2th column) value with a variable in a file. So I am using the command:

```
varz="zipval"
awk -v  VAR=$varz '{$2=VAR}1' OutputFile.log
```

The awk substitute all the tabs to space after processing. So I have used  OFS="\t" .

But it removes every space to tabs
`Sandnes<tab>gecom<tab>Hansen<tab>zipval<tab>Timoteivn<tab>10`

How to handle it.
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [how can I supply bash variables as fields for print in awk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13619521/how-can-i-supply-bash-variables-as-fields-for-print-in-awk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this script to pass column no to your awk script:

```
varz="zipval"
awk -v VAR=$varz -v N=6 '{sub($N, VAR)}1' OutputFile.log
```

Comment: Thanks Its working. But the Awk substitution replaces tabs to space.

Comment: That seems like an entirely different problem to me than the question. But if you post some example scenario in your question I can try to give you an answer.

Comment: Alright try my edited answer now. It will preserve tabs and spaces "as is".

Comment: Don't do that, it does NOT work. It will fail if your target field contains RE metacharacters (+, ?, *, (, [, etc.) or if it is a substring of some earlier field (e.g. if field N is "the" but field N-1 is "their"). It will also fail if varz contains any spaces or contains any globbing characters.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that awk splits your input on `FS=[ \t]+` and then reassembles it with `OFS=' '` or `OFS='\t'`. I don't think you can get around doing an extra split. Something like this works:

```
<data awk -v VAR="$varz" 'BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" } { split($1, a, " +"); $1 = a[1]" "VAR } 1'
```

Output:

```
Sandnes zipval^IHansen^IOla Timoteivn 10
```

Answer (score 0):

The below is working fine at my place:

```
> setenv var "hi"
> echo "1 2 3 4 5 6 7" | awk -v var1=$var '{$6=var1}1'
1 2 3 4 5 hi 7
>
```

Comment: try it after setting var to "hello world" and then once you fix that try it again with tabs instead of spaces between fields 2 and 3 and imagine that your file is tab-separated so $1 is actually "1 2" and $2 is "3 4 5 6 7".

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post your desired output or even tell us which specific text you wanted replaced ("2th field" could mean several things) so this is a guess, but assuming your input file is tab-separated fields, you just need to quote your shell variable and assign FS as well as OFS:

```
varz="zipval"
awk -v VAR="$varz" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {$2=VAR} 1' OutputFile.log
```

I'd also recommend you don't use all-upper case for your variable name since that's used to identify awk builtin variables (NR, NF, etc.).